# Pagination Undefined index: id

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Hello guys recently i just make some simple pagination php, i have some page that require where condition for 'id' that will query from database. and it is working

But when I'm using the pagination and it is require some id from url that I'm going , the code doesn't read the id , here is my code

```
$page=1;//Default page
$limit=1;//Records per page buat nampilin banyak nya
$start=0;//starts displaying records from 0
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=''){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
    $start=($page-1)*$limit;


$sql=mysql_query("select id_jualan from jualan where kategori='$_GET[id]'"); 
$rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from jualan where kategori='$_GET[id]' order by id_jualan ASC LIMIT $start, $limit");

$no=1;
```

and here is the code for call the page

```
<?php echo pagination($limit,$page,'gallery.php?page=',$rows);  //call function to show pagination ?>
```

but if i don't using where condition the pagination work correctly , 
the question is ...
how the second page recognize the id for where condition ??
thanks a lot hope there is a right answer for this :))

Comment: Did you try actually passing it to the server?

Comment: Where is the `pagination()` function, plus it's probably because `id` parameter is not set in url.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables says hello.](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: the pagination function is set, and id parameter is set too in the url , in the first page it is work correctly but in the second they say Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 17

Comment: line 15 and 17 is the line mysql_query on above

Comment: @user2699752 You do know you're open to SQL injections right? As ThiefMaster was implying.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index: id -> you are using $_GET['id'] if ID is not defined in your url. Use:

```
if(isSet($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'])
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select id_jualan from jualan where kategori='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id]) . "'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: On the Second Page
before :
Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 17

after i change with your code :

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 163

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 163

Notice: Undefined variable: rows in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gallery.php on line 181

Comment: You are using variables and indexes which are not defined. Use isSet() method on all of these variables/indexes.